# CallbackOnCollectedDelegate was detected even with static delegate

Tags: c#, delegates, unmanaged, aforge, keyboard-hook

**Here is keyboard hook code:**

```
   class globalKeyboardHook
        {
            #region Constant, Structure and Delegate Definitions

            public delegate int keyboardHookProc(int code, int wParam, ref keyboardHookStruct lParam);
            public static keyboardHookProc callbackDelegate;

            public struct keyboardHookStruct
            {
                public int vkCode;
                public int scanCode;
                public int flags;
                public int time;
                public int dwExtraInfo;
            }

            const int WH_KEYBOARD_LL = 13;
            const int WM_KEYDOWN = 0x100;
            const int WM_KEYUP = 0x101;
            const int WM_SYSKEYDOWN = 0x104;
            const int WM_SYSKEYUP = 0x105;
            #endregion

            #region Instance Variables

            public List<Keys> HookedKeys = new List<Keys>();
            private static IntPtr hhook = IntPtr.Zero;

            #endregion

            #region Events

            public event KeyEventHandler KeyDown;
            public event KeyEventHandler KeyUp;

            #endregion

            #region Constructors and Destructors

            public globalKeyboardHook()
            {
                hook();
                GC.KeepAlive(callbackDelegate);
            }

            ~globalKeyboardHook()
            {
                unhook();
            }

            #endregion

            #region Public Methods

            public void hook()
            {
                IntPtr hInstance = LoadLibrary("User32");
                callbackDelegate = new keyboardHookProc(hookProc);
                hhook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, callbackDelegate, hInstance, 0);
                if (hhook == IntPtr.Zero) throw new Win32Exception();
            }

            public void unhook()
            {
                bool ok = UnhookWindowsHookEx(hhook);
                if (!ok) throw new Win32Exception();
                callbackDelegate = null;
            }

            public int hookProc(int code, int wParam, ref keyboardHookStruct lParam)
            {
                if (code >= 0)
                {
                    Keys key = (Keys)lParam.vkCode;
                    if (HookedKeys.Contains(key))
                    {
                        KeyEventArgs kea = new KeyEventArgs(key);
                        if ((wParam == WM_KEYDOWN || wParam == WM_SYSKEYDOWN) && (KeyDown != null))
                        {
                            KeyDown(this, kea);
                        }
                        else if ((wParam == WM_KEYUP || wParam == WM_SYSKEYUP) && (KeyUp != null))
                        {
                            KeyUp(this, kea);
                        }
                        if (kea.Handled)
                            return 1;
                    }
                }
                return CallNextHookEx(hhook, code, wParam, ref lParam); // Exception on this line
            }
            #endregion

            #region DLL imports

            [DllImport("user32.dll")]
            static extern IntPtr SetWindowsHookEx(int idHook, keyboardHookProc callback, IntPtr hInstance, uint threadId);

            [DllImport("user32.dll")]
            static extern bool UnhookWindowsHookEx(IntPtr hInstance);

            [DllImport("user32.dll")]
            static extern int CallNextHookEx(IntPtr idHook, int nCode, int wParam, ref keyboardHookStruct lParam);

            [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
            static extern IntPtr LoadLibrary(string lpFileName);
            #endregion
        }
```

**When I initialize it in Child Form constructor first nothing happens, you can press all you want but nothing gets to event:**

```
private globalKeyboardHook kh = new globalKeyboardHook();

public FrmMainForm(FrmVideo owner)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            _videoForm = owner;

            try
            {
                _videoDevices = new FilterInfoCollection(FilterCategory.VideoInputDevice);

                if (_videoDevices.Count == 0)
                {
                    throw new ApplicationException();
                }

                foreach (FilterInfo device in _videoDevices)
                {
                    camerasCombo.Items.Add(device.Name);
                }

                camerasCombo.SelectedIndex = 1;
            }
            catch (ApplicationException)
            {
                camerasCombo.Items.Add("No local capture devices");
                _videoDevices = null;
            }

            kh.KeyUp += new KeyEventHandler(kh_KeyUp);
            kh.hook();
        }


    void kh_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.F12)
            _videoForm.TakeOver = !_videoForm.TakeOver;

        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Escape)
            Application.Exit();
    }
```

**Until I call piece of Aforge code for capturing from webcam, this starts streaming on Parent form:**

```
  var videoSource = new VideoCaptureDevice(_videoDevices[camerasCombo.SelectedIndex].MonikerString)
        {
            DesiredFrameSize = new Size(Globals.FrameWidth, Globals.FrameHeight),
            DesiredFrameRate = 12
        };

        if (videoSource != null)
        {
            _videoForm.Device = videoSource;
            _videoForm.Start();
            button1.Enabled = false;
        }
```

**After that on any keypress I get:
CallbackOnCollectedDelegate was detected on return next hook, any ideas?**

Oh, and I am unhooking on dispose of form:

```
   protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing && (components != null))
            {
                components.Dispose();
            }
            kh.unhook();
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }
```

Comment: Do you really need a keyboard hook? Or are global hotkeys enough?

Comment: @CodesInChaos can you explain the difference?

Comment: With a global hotkey windows notifies you if one of the specific keys (or key combinations) you're interested in is pressed. With a keyboard hook you receive every keypress. This can have negative effects on input latency and is conceptually the wrong approach.

Comment: @CodesInChaos My only requirement is that I can capture keys without application(Form) in focus. Can you show me a way to implement it?

Comment: If you only need a couple of hotkeys, use the `RegisterHotkey` windows API.

Comment: @CodesInChaos Thanks, I got it working using RegisterHotKey, but I will leave this question because I would like to know what was wrong with above code.

Comment: Add debug checks in `hook` that you didn't call `hook` yet, and check in `unhook` that you hooked. Also make sure you don't unhook while the handler is running.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This requires psychic debugging and infer something you didn't document.  The oddity is that the MDA is triggered when you call CallNextHookEx().  Which is somewhat strange, the callback to your hook procedure actually worked.  That delegate object wasn't collected.  It is the *next* hook procedure call that failed.

There's a simple explanation for that: you called SetWindowsHookEx() more than once.  Now using a static variable to store the delegate object will seriously bite, as static variables usually do, it is capable of storing only *one* delegate object.  The second time you call hook(), it will overwrite the delegate of the first hook and it is thus no longer prevented from getting garbage collected.  Which indeed triggers the MDA on the CallNextHookEx() since that will call the hook procedure for the first hook.

So your hook() method needs to be improved to this:

```
public void hook()
{
    if (callbackDelegate != null) 
        throw new InvalidOperationException("Cannot hook more than once");
    // etc..
}
```

It is actually not illegal to hook more than once, Windows doesn't mind.  Just don't declare the variable static.